# I can't change the google fonts' weight

Tags: css, fonts, google-fonts

I am using google fonts and was trying to change the weight of a font (Montserrat). I have chosen the 100 and 900 weights and got this code to copy:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;900&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet">
```

then I tried to style it:

```
h1{
 font-family:Montserrat;
 font-weight:900;}
```

but it didn't work

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work because it worked fine for me. https://codepen.io/PoornakaB/pen/wvredWB

Comment: you needed to popper font-family provided from google font. ```font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;``` also make sure google font is loaded!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below it will work. The reason your css code doesn't work is that you didn't wrap Montserrat with ''. Enjoy coding!

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```